# What does the [0]*x syntax do in Python?

Tags: python, math, programming-languages

A flash question, I'm looking at the following code

```
from __future__ import division
import math
import time

def dft(x, inverse = False, verbose = False) :
    t = time.clock()
    N = len(x)
    inv = -1 if not inverse else 1
    X =[0] * N
    for k in xrange(N) :
        for n in xrange(N) :
            X[k] += x[n] * math.e**(inv * 2j * math.pi * k * n / N)
        if inverse :
            X[k] /= N
    t = time.clock() - t
    if verbose :
        print "Computed","an inverse" if inverse else "a","DFT of size",N,
        print "in",t,"sec."
    return X
```

and I'm wondering (I do not know python):

- what does the X =[0] * N line do?
- why the double asterisk ** ?

Comment: Thank you all for your answers!

Comment: why didnt you try by yourself? For example, something like `>>> [0] * 10` in your interpreter shell would have been enough...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `x = [0] * n` is demonstrated here:

```
>>> [0]*10
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

It 'multiplies' the list elements

```
>>> [1, 2, 3] * 3
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

The `**` is the power operator

```
>>> 3**2
9
```

Although be careful, it can also be **kwargs (in a different context), see more about that here [Proper way to use **kwargs in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098549/proper-way-to-use-kwargs-in-python)

Comment: Do you have a reference to the `[0] * x` syntax in the python documentation?  I cannot find it anywhere.  I also can't find a standard name for it.

Comment: Works similar to Groovy: ```assert  ['a', 'b', 'c'] * 5 == [a, b, c, a, b, c, a, b, c, a, b, c, a, b, c]```. I guess Groovy (created in 2003) "borrowed" a lot of ideas from Python (created in 1991) (and perhaps JavaScript?)

Answer (score 37):

The `[0] * x` creates a list with `x` elements. So,

```
>>> [ 0 ] * 5
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>>
```

Be warned that they all point to the same object. This is cool for immutables like integers but a pain for things like lists.

```
>>> t = [[]] * 5
>>> t
[[], [], [], [], []]
>>> t[0].append(5)
>>> t
[[5], [5], [5], [5], [5]]
>>>
```

The `**` operator is used for exponentation.

```
>>> 5 ** 2 
25
```

Comment: +1 for the same mutable object, I would fix "with `x` elements" because you can multiply lists that have multiple elements.

Answer (score 7):

1. `X =[0] * N`, produces a list of size N, with all N elements being the value zero. for example, `X = [0] * 8`, produces a list of size 8.

   X = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

   Pictorial representation will be like,

[image: The result of command [0] * 8]

Technically, all eight cells of the list reference the same object. This is because of the fact that lists are referential structures in python.

and, if you try to assign a new value to list, say `X[2] = 10`, this does not technically change the value of the existing integer instance. This computes a new integer, with value 10, and sets cell 2 to reference the newly computed value.

Pictorial representation,

[image]

2. `**` is power operator and computes the power of a number. for example, `5 ** 2` results in 25.

Answer (score 4):

`X = [0] * N` creates an array of zeros of `N` length. For example:

```
>>> [0] * 10
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

`**` is the [power operator](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator).

```
>>> 2 ** 2
4
```

Answer (score 2):

> what does the X =[0] * N line do?

`[0]` is a sequence containing a single element – `0`. Multiplying a sequence times `n` means concatenating it `n` times to itself. That is, the result is a sequence containing `n` zeros.

> why the double asterisk ** ?

It’s the power operator: `b ** e` = *b*<sup>*e*</sup>.

Answer (score 0):

1) It initialises a list containing N 0's.

2) `**` is the exponentiation operator

Answer (score 0):

`[0] * N` creates a list of size N which contains only 0's

the `**` is a notation for raising the *left side* to the power of *right side*

Disclaimer: 
`[a] * N` where `a` is a reference to an object will copy the reference, it won't make copies of `a` inside the list generated