# longest common subsequence matrix difference python

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

I'm working on a dynamic programming problem **(longest common subsequence)**

**My issue:** building the matrix.

I initially build my matrix with dp1. but it kept churning out the wrong answers. Then I referenced other answers and used dp2, which produces the right answer.

**For example:**

s1 = ELGGYJWKTDHLXJRBJLRYEJWVSUFZKYHOIKBGTVUTTOCGMLEXWDSXEBKRZTQUVCJNGKKRMUUBACVOEQKBFFYBUQEMYNENKYYGUZSP

s2 = FRVIFOVJYQLVZMFBNRUTIYFBMFFFRZVBYINXLDDSVMPWSQGJZYTKMZIPEGMVOUQBKYEWEYVOLSHCMHPAZYTENRNONTJWDANAMFRX

**The right answer should be 27.**

- dp1 gives 30
- dp2 gives 27

I'm puzzled. What's the difference? isn't "for _ in range(m+1)" essentially iterating whatever is before by m+1 times? please help me out.

```
def commonChild(s1, s2):
    n, m = len(s1), len(s2)
    dp1 = [[0] * (n+1)] * (m+1)
    dp2 = [[0] * (n+1) for _ in range(m+1)]

    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            if s2[i] == s1[j]:
                dp[i+1][j+1] = dp[i][j] +1
            else:
                dp[i+1][j+1] = max(dp[i][j+1], dp[i+1][j])

    return dp[-1][-1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> a=[[0] * (5) for i in range(4)]
>>> a
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> a[0][0]=1
>>> a
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> a=[[0] * (5) ]*4
>>> a[0][0]=1
>>> a
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

You can see the difference yourself,

in  `[[0]*(n+1)]*(m+1)` it is referring to the same array `[0] * (n+1)`  so changing one array value changes the same value in all

Comment: then is there a difference between a=[["0" for x in range(4)]for x in range(4)] and a=[[0] * (5) for i in range(4)]?

Comment: why is that so?

Comment: @KwokWenJian [thislink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007881/what-does-the-0x-syntax-do-in-python) has the answer you are looking for