# Difference between list defined with multiplication and without

Tags: python

Is there an explainer on the difference between?

```
aL, bL = [[], []]
xL, yL = [[]] * 2
```

Superficially, they should be the same.

```
[[], []] == [[]] * 2
True
```

But they behave differently.

```
aL.append("a")
xL.append("x")
bL
[]
yL
['x']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
>>> [[]] * 2 == [[], []] # True

>>> a1, b1 = [[], []]
>>> id(a1) # 4425627680
>>> id(b1) # 4425627760

>>> a2, b2 = [[]] * 2
>>> id(a2) # 4424875616
>>> id(b2) # 4424875616
```

When you utilize the `*` expression to generate a list of lists, Python is copying the inner object of `[[]]`, and copying its reference over. Therefore, when doing `[[]] * 2`, you end up with a list of lists in which *all* of the inner lists are the same object. If you are still confused, I recommend checking out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53183277/1305461).

Now why `[[]] * 2 == [[], []]` is True, this is easy to observe:

```py
>>> bool([[], []]) # True
>>> bool([[]] * 2) # True
>>> bool([]) # False
```

A list with anything inside always evaluates to `True`, therefore you are doing `True == True` which is of course `True`.