# How to change individual cells in a matrix?

Tags: python, list, matrix

I am trying to understand why the following behaviour exists in Python.

If I make two equivalent matrices

```
matrix1 = [[False] * 3] * 3
matrix2 = [[False for x in range(3)] for y in range(3)]
```

Then I try to make the top left cell equal to `True`.

```
matrix1[0][0] = True
matrix2[0][0] = True
```

Each array was changed in a different way.

```
matrix1 is now [[True, False, False], [True, False, False], [True, False, False]]
matrix2 is now [[True, False, False], [False, False, False], [False, False, False]]
```

`matrix2` is the behaviour I was expecting. Why does `matrix1` behave differently?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly) [List changes unexpectedly after assignment. Why is this and how can I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2612815/8881141)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `[]*3`, each element points to the same object, so changing one changes the others. You can think of it as a way to multiply the elements in a list.

When you use `[for x in range(3)]`, it creates three separate items. Changing one item doesn't affect the others.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007881/what-does-the-0x-syntax-do-in-python/6007901 for more info.