# How to define a class with a variable property

Tags: python, class

I am working with 2 classes defined as `zone` and `system`. The `system` is supposed to contain several zones, but the number can vary. So, I have defined for example the class `zone` as such:

```
class zone(object):
    def __init__ (self,
        nameZone = None,
        height = None,
        width = None):

        self.nameZone = nameZone
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
```

and the class `system` as follows:

```
   class system(object):
    def __init__(self,
                 SystemName = None,
                 NumberOfZones = None,
                 zone = None):

        self.SystemName = SystemName
        self.NumberOfZones = NumberOfZones
        self.zone = zone
```

So for example I would like to know how do I go about defining the class SYSTEM with a variable number of parameters? Like for example I could have:

```
 building = system(2, apart1, apart2)
 building2 = system(3, apart1,apart2,apart3)
```

where of course apart1, 2, and 3 are defined as class `zone`.

I have tried something like:

```
for i in range(self.NumberOfZones)
         self.zone = zone
```

But this doesn't work obviously.

Comment: Why not to use mutable like self.Zones and then append all zones into it.

Comment: Not a complete duplicate, but handles the problem for the most part: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098549/proper-way-to-use-kwargs-in-python

Answer (score 0):

You can use the variable args features.

```
class system(object):
    def __init__(self, SystemName, *zones):
        self.SystemName = SystemName
        self.zones = list(zones)

    # The number of zones is the length of the zones list.
```

Then you can just put any number, without even having to specify how many. Python will just collect all paramenters after the name as zones.

Comment: You don't need to call `list(zones)` as zones is a list.

Comment: The problem I have now is this: AttributeError: 'zone' object has no attribute 'append' . Because I am using something like this: self.fileinwhichiwrite.append(line), so that I can write all the results I want to print out in a text file. Is there a way arround using this self.file.append(line) ?

Comment: @Jakob, no, zones is a tuple. If you want it mutable after (such as append to it) you need to convert it to a list.

Comment: @caran I'm not sure what you're talking about. There is no `self.file` in your example.

Comment: Yes, I omitted that in my example cos I thought it was not important.In fact my full class definition would have also a line for this like: def __init__(self,
                 SystemName = None,
                 NumberOfZones = None,
                 zone = None,
   filelines = None):

        self.SystemName = SystemName
        self.NumberOfZones = NumberOfZones
        self.zone = zone
        
 if filelines is None:
            self.filelines  = []
        else:
            self.filelines  = filelines

Answer (score 0):

```
class System(object):
    def __init__(self, system_name = None, *zones):
    self.system_name = system_name
    self.number_of_zones = len(zones)
    self.zones = zones
```

I cleaned up to PEP8 slightly and left in number_of_zones.

Answer (score 0):

Using the varargs is OK, but I would say it is clearer to pass explicitly a list of zones. That way you can add different named parameters in the future if needed.