# python positional args and keyword args

Tags: python, func, function

I am reading the source codes of mercurial, and found such a func def in commands.py:

```
def import_(ui, repo, patch1=None, *patches, **opts):
    ...
```

in python, postional args must be put ahead of keyword args. But here, `patch1` is a keyword argument, followed by a positional argument `*patches`. why is this OK?

Comment: Have you solved this yet? If you have, it would be good if you would select the answer that made you solve the issue as "accepted", and upvote all the useful ones (if you haven't done that already!). :)

Comment: sorry, I've been very busy all these days. I will now read about your answers and select one. Thanks for all of you:)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just have a look into the [PEP 3102](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/) also it seems its somehow related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098549/proper-way-to-use-kwargs-in-python).

To summarize, patches and opts are there to accept variable arguments but the later is to accept keyword arguments. The keyword arguments are passed as a dictionary where as the [variable positional arguments would be wrapped as tuples](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) .

From your example

```
def import_(ui, repo, patch1=None, *patches, **opts):
```

Any positional parameters after `u1,repo and patch1` would be wrapped as tuples in patches. Any keyword arguments following the variable positional arguments  would be wrapped as Dictionary objects through opts.

Another important thing is that, the onus lies with the caller to ensure that the condition `non-keyword arg after keyword arg` is not violated.

So something that violates this would raise a syntax error..

For example

Calls like

```
 import_(1,2,3,test="test")
 import_(1,2,3,4,test="test")
 import_(1,2,3,4,5)
 import_(1,2,patch1=3,test="test")
```

are valid, but

```
import_(1,2,3,patch1=4,5)
```

would raise a syntax error `SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg`

In the first valid case `import_(1,2,3,test="test")`

```
u1 = 1, repo = 2, patch1 = 3, patches = () and opts={"test":"test"}
```

In the second valid case `import_(1,2,3,patch1=4,test="test")`

```
u1 = 1, repo = 2, patch1 = 3 , patches = (4) and opts={"test":"test"}
```

In the third valid case `import_(1,2,3,4,5)`

```
u1 = 1, repo = 2, patch1 = 3 , patches=(4,5), and opts={}
```

In the fourth valid case `import_(1,2,patch1=3,test="test")`

```
u1 = 1, repo = 2, patch1 = 3 , patches=(), and opts={"test":"test"}
you can use patch1 as a keywords argument but doing so you cannot wrap any variable positional arguments within patches
```

Comment: Thanks for your examples and references, I think I get my answer. python's arguments are so flexible, I didn't know about it well enough before this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Probably you are confusing the function definition and the function call syntax a bit.

`patch1` is not a keyword arg, it's a positional arg with a default argument value assigned.

`*patches` is an argument list, and not a positional argument.

---

Please have a look at this section from the official tutorials:

- http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions

Now let me summarize the main points using this function as an example:

```
def f1(a1, a2, a3=None, *args, **kwargs):
  print a1, a2, a3, args, kwargs
```

**Function Definition**

You have a number of arguments that are defined explicitly by name (`a1`, `a2` and `a3`), of which `a3` will be default initialized by `None` if not supplied during call. The arguments `a1` and `a2` need to be supplied in any valid call of that function.

The function may be called with additional arguments that will appear in the dictionary `kwargs` (when supplied by keyword) or in the list `args` (when not supplied by keyword).
If `args` and `kwargs` would not be present in the function definition, the caller would not be allowed to add more arguments besides those explicitly named in the function definition for the function call.

In the function definition you need to specify the explicit arguments without default initializer first, second the explicit arguments with default initializer, third the  argument list, lastly the keyword argument dictionary.

**Function Call**

There are various ways to call the function. For example will the following calls produce equal results:

```
f1(1, 2)       # pass a1 and a2 as positional arguments
f1(a2=2, a1=1) # pass a1 and a2 as keyword arguments
f1(1, a2=2)    # pass a1 as positional argument, a2 as keyword argument
```

That is, the function arguments are resolved either by their position (positional, or non-keyword arguments) or by their specified name (keyword arguments).

When calling the function you need to put the non-keyword arguments first and lastly the keyword arguments, e.g.

```
# demonstrate how some additional positional and keyword arguments are passed
f1(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, a4=8, a5=9, a6=10)
# prints:
# 1 2 3 (4, 5, 6, 7) {'a5': 9, 'a4': 8, 'a6': 10}
```

Now, positional arguments that don't fit into the list of specified arguments in the function definition will be appended to the argument list `*args`, and keyword arguments that don't fit into the list of specified arguments in the function definition will be inserted into the keyword argument dictionary `**kwargs`.

Comment: I find this definition slightly ambiguous (although not incorrect). See edits in my answer on why.

Comment: See my example, you can use patch1 as keyword argument provided there are no positional arguments after it.

Answer (score 2):

Because passing the key to a keyword argument can be optional if the position of it is unambiguous. Observe:

```
>>> def f(ui, patch1=None, *patches, **opts):
...     print patch1
... 
>>> f(1, 2)
2
>>> f(1, patch1='a', 3)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
>>> f(1, 'a', 3)
a
```

As you can see, omitting the key of `patch1` render that argument a non-keyword one, thus not triggering the `SyntaxError` exception.

---

**EDIT:** moooeeeep in his answer says that

> "patch1 is not a keyword arg, it's a positional arg with a default argument value assigned."

This is not wrong, but the following-case IMO, illustrates why such definition is ambiguous:

```
>>> def f(ui, p1=None, p2=None, *patches, **opts):
...    print p1, p2
... 
>>> f(1, 'a', 'b', 3)  #p2 is a positional argument with default value?
a b
>>> f(1, p2='b')  #p2 is a keyword argument?
None b
```

HTH!

Comment: yes ... in my opinion, it's a run-time ambiguity, not a define-time ambiguity. As the OP is concerned with the function definition [I was describing the function definition](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8486166/1025391). But I acknowledge, this is a good point to note.

Answer (score 2):

I believe when **calling** a function with:

```
function(arg1="value")
```

This would be using a "keyword" argument, but when **defining** a function's interface with:

```
def function(arg1="value"):
```

you're defining a "default value". ()

So to answer your question; Having a default value after a positional argument is perfectly normal, and so is calling a function with a non-keyword argument before a keyword.

Also note, when calling a function, you **cannot** have a non-keyword argument after a keyword.