# PyGMO custom class with __init__ error

Tags: python-2.7, optimization, parallel-processing

I am working on a parallelized optimization problem in `PyGMO`. Unfortunately the docs are not very helpful. According to [these guidelines](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/pygmo/newdocs/pygmo.pdf), I am riting my problem as

```
import PyGMO as pygmo
class my_problem(pygmo.base):
    def __init__(self,model,config,pars,**kwargs):
        # Does some parameter definition according to input arguments model, config etc...
        ...

        # Invoke base class as required by PyGMO
        super(my_problem,self).__init__(self.__dim)

    def _objfun_impl(self,x):
        ...
        f = ...  # Cost function to optimize
        return (f,)

# Main
model = 'ei'
config = 'x1'
args = (...)
prob = my_problem(model,config,args)
algo = pygmo.algorithm.de(gen=20)
isl = pygmo.island(algo,prob,20)
print isl.population.champion.f
isl.evolve(10)
print isl.population.champion.f
```

This does not work and produce the following error:

```
File     "/home/maurizio/Dropbox/Stability_Analysis_network/mymain.py", line 643, in main_routine
isl = pygmo.island(algo,prob,20)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyGMO/core/__init__.py", line 239, in island
return _generic_island_ctor(None, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyGMO/core/__init__.py", line 132, in _generic_island_ctor
return py_island(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyGMO/core/__init__.py", line 119, in _generic_island_ctor
super(type(self), self).__init__(*ctor_args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyGMO/core/__init__.py", line 48, in __init__
_core._base_island.__init__(self, *args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyGMO/problem/_base.py", line 36, in __get_deepcopy__
return deepcopy(self)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/copy.py", line 190, in deepcopy
y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/copy.py", line 329, in _reconstruct
y = callable(*args)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (1 given)
```

Any idea to what `__init__` is referring to and what parameters are missing? I suspect that it is a problem with my class definition.

Comment: I don't see you calling your class in the code...

Comment: Sorry, I am editing that... The post was a generalization.

Comment: @alec_djinn I suspect it is a problem with `super` call and the base class `__init__` ...

Comment: I think you need to pass `my_problem` to super `super(my_problem,self).__init__(dim)`

Comment: @alec_djinn  Sorry that was another typo. The code does so... The problem seems rather that I am trying to use `__init__` from `base` which is different in call from the one defined by `my_problem`... so the question is rather how to inherit `__init__` from `base` but doing some other stuff meanwhile...

Comment: still, you are passing self.dim to init, instead, try passing just dim as in my previous example, of course, you have to add dim to your __init__ definition.

Comment: @alec_djinn Nope. It does not solve the issue. In fact the error is now `TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 5 arguments (1 given)`

Comment: Now you are sure that that is the init you are misscalling... what about passing also model,config,pars,**kwargs to it?

Comment: @alec_djinn I don't think I can: If I understood the `super(my_problem.self).__init__(...)` correctly, I am making my `my_problem` class use the `__init__` method from `pygmo.problem.base` class, which has its own fixed parameters... which are not mine...

Comment: but you have refactored that init in your class... check here https://esa.github.io/pygmo/tutorials/adding_a_new_algorithm.html, basically the same example you have, he did not passed iter because in his __init__ there is a default value of 10

Comment: @alec_djinn so you are saying that if I set some defaults I avoid the problem? The error actually changes in this way and it gives a stream error. I can't follow up right now as I'm off my pc... but please let's touch base in the next hours or tomorrow as soon as I'm back on my code.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by the mismatch between input arguments of `my_problem.__init__(...)` (i.e. the Child class) and the `base.__init__` (i.e. the Parent class). If defaults for these parameters are not provided then a conflict results by the inheritance of `__init__` by `super(my_problem,self)` from `base`. In practice, a corrected working version is:

```
import PyGMO as pygmo
class my_problem(pygmo.base):
    def __init__(self,model='ei',config='conf1',pars=[1]*20):
        # Does some parameter definition according to input arguments model, config etc...
    ...

    self.__dim = 3
    ...

    # Invoke base class as required by PyGMO
    super(my_problem,self).__init__(self.__dim)

    def _objfun_impl(self,x):
        ...
        f = ...  # Cost function to optimize
        return (f,)

# Main
...
```

It is not possible instead to pass `**kwargs` to the child class insofar as `base` is hard coded and should be changed accordingly to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21660834/why-cant-pass-args-and-kwargs-in-init-of-a-child-class).