# How to preserve argument suggestions when using *args **kwargs in Python subclass

Tags: python, class, super

In python when creating a subclass we often pass necessary arguments to the superclass using the construction `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)` like so:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

However, if I do this I will lose all argument hints and docstrings from superclass (A in this case) and will be left with `*args` and `**kwargs`.

When using decorators a similar problem is solved via `functools.wraps`. My question is **is there similarly elegant solution to the situation with `__init__` of a subclass?** Maybe using `functools.update_wrapper`?

Comment: Asked in https://github.com/python/typing/discussions/1079#discussion-3878409 also. I'm surprised that this doesn't have a good solution from what I can see.

Comment: Also, possibly a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626279/inheritance-best-practice-args-kwargs-or-explicitly-specifying-parameters.