# django admin list data using default filter

Tags: django

i have model like this

```
### models.py
class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
    have_recipe = models.BooleanField()

### admin.py
admin.register(Pizza)
class PizzaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'name', 'price')
    exclude = ('have_recipe',)
```

when I enter `localhost:8000/admin/pizza` i can see all of pizza objects,

but, I want to make admin pizza list show only `have_recipe=True` objects and nobody can't control this filter in admin page

is there any solution??

Comment: Related question here which will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12354099/override-default-queryset-in-django-admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the [**`get_queryset(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset) and work with:

```
# admin.py

@admin.register(Pizza)
class PizzaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'name', 'price')
    exclude = ('have_recipe',)
    
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(
            have_recipe=True
        )
```

You should also use `@admin.register(Pizza)` as a *decorator*, so with a leading `@`.

Comment: Little mistake here, in the docs `get_queryset` only takes `request`. It should be `def get_queryset(self, request)` and the super call should be `super().get_queryset(request).filter(...)`.

Comment: @DeanElliott: but this works as well. It is usually better here to work with `*args` and `**kwargs` since (a) it makes it easier to understand that we do a supercall, and (b) a mixin can slightly change the `get_queryset` and its callers. Finally (c) it is possible that later versions of Django will redefine the `get_queryset` function, so in that case we do not make it version-specific to make a super call.

Comment: My bad, no mistake here then, if you are changing the arguments though I would recommend using `get_queryset(self, request, **kwargs)` which supports your points B and C but is more readable with the explicit `request` parameter. There are some good discussions around this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626279/inheritance-best-practice-args-kwargs-or-explicitly-specifying-parameters

Comment: Using it or not isn't that important here though. Your solution certainly works well and will help @JadeHan with their answer. Ignore me :)

Comment: @DeanElliott: well I think what would be nice is to work with a `@wraps` decorator in that case, such that the parameters of the the original method still show up with `help(PizzaAdmin.get_queryset)`. But I agree that using `request` or `*args` is opinion-based. :)