# Passing custom keyword arguments to a function

Tags: python, arguments, keyword, keyword-argument

I have a program that has an `update_database()` function but I don't know what the keyword arguments will be until runtime, so one time the function is called it may need to be:

```
table_name = 'example1'
update_database(table_name, column1='...', column3='...')
```

but another time it may be:

```
table_name = 'example2'
update_database(table_name, column5='...', column2='...')
```

So the function calls will need to be a mix of regular arguments and keyword arguments. The keyword argument names I have access to as a list so I can format them any old way I like easy enough but I m not sure if this behaviour is even possible in python.

Does anybody know if/how this may be possible?

UPDATE:

Its also worth noting that the `update_database()` function is part of an imported module so i cant modify its definition, I could wrap it somehow but I'm not sure if this gains me anything.

Comment: See e.g. [this old question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098549/proper-way-to-use-kwargs-in-python).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always use undefined number of keyword arguments in your original function, like:

*(In the case of keyword arguments, you have a simple dictionary instead of a list)*

```
def update_database(tname, **columns):
    for key, value in columns.items():
        # do something with key-value pairs
```

***UPDATE:***

So I guess, this is what we are talking about in the comment section, am I correct?

```
# Create dictionaries with keys as keywords and values as argument values
kwargs0 = {'arg0': 0, 'arg1': 2, 'arg2': 5}
kwargs1 = {'arg99': 1, 'arg13': None, 'arg0': 7}

# Call the function and UNPACK the dictionaries
update_database('db_name', **kwargs0)
update_database('db_name', **kwargs1)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the ability to change the definition as `update_database()` is a function from an external module

Comment: I can show you how to wrap a function with another, but I'm not quite sure, what is the goal you want to achieve. Do you want to rename the keywords, before passing to this `update_database` function? Or do you want to filter them, to pass only some of the keywords? Or?

Comment: Say I have a dict `keywords = {'arg1': 'value', 'arg2': 'value'}`, I'd like to use that dict as an argument for a function something like: `update_database('db_name', args=keywords)` rather than `update_database('db_name', arg1='value', arg2='value')` as those args may change at runtime, I hope that makes sense

Comment: I updated my answer, see if that fits your needs @jonathantopf!

Comment: thats exactly it, thanks!