# In Python 3.x how do I create a simple proxy function for another function that is a pure pass through?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python 3.x, I want to create a proxy function **_proxy** for a specific known function **proxiedFunc** and guarantee that all arguments passed are "forwarded" exactly as if they were passed directly to the **proxiedFunc**.

```
# Pseudo-Python code
def _proxy(???generic_parameters???):
        return proxiedFunc(???arguments???)
```

What I mean by "pure pass through" -> The implementation of the **_proxy** method should not be affected by (non-)compatible changes to the **proxiedMethod**, assuming the name of the function doesn't change (SOLID principles).  Obviously, callers of **_proxy** would need to be modified if **proxiedMethod** is changed incompatibly (i.e. I'm not intending for _proxy to be an adapter, but that would be a possibility).

Comment: [*args and **kwargs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098549/proper-way-to-use-kwargs-in-python) might help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The generic way of taking "anything" in a function definition is using `*args, **kwargs`.

The same syntax is used for passing those args when calling another function.

```
def _proxy(*args, **kwargs):
        return proxiedFunc(*args, **kwargs)
```

The single `*` (e.g. `*args`) captures the positional arguments, and the double (e.g. `**kwargs`) captures the keyword arguments.

`args` and `kwargs` are the names you give to those argument-containers.  By convention, the name of the "any-positional-args" argument is `args` or `a` (its type is `tuple`), and the name of the "any-keyword-args" argument is `kwargs` or `kw` (its type is `dict`).

Answer (score 0):

I, too, wanted to find a way to do that, so I wrote a function for that. I posted it to github: https://github.com/make-itrain/function-proxy

Basically, what it does is:

```
def a(p1, p2, p3=3, *args, p4=228, p18=11, **kwargs):
    # any function, doesn't matter
    pass


def b(p4, p2, *args):
    # some overlapping arguments
    # it too doesn't matter, what's inside here
    print(p4, p2, args)


args, kwargs = proxy_function(b, a, {"args": ("replaced args",)}, 322, "some_random_arg", 1337, 
                              "arguments", ('anything',), 1, abc=338, cbd="here too?")
b(*args, **kwargs)
```

Prints `228 some_random_arg ('replaced args',)`. Cool, isn't it?