# How to set default kwargs?

Tags: python

I want to set defaults for my kwargs how would I do that?

```
def function(arg1, arg2, **kwargs, kwargs['a'] = 1):
    print(kwargs['a'])

function(1, 2)
```

Result would be `1`.

Comment: Why not just `a=1`? Or you could use [`.get`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098549/proper-way-to-use-kwargs-in-python).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define each default argument individually, then use `kwargs` for the rest:

```
def foo(arg1, arg2, a=1, **kwargs):
```

Comment: Make it `def foo(arg1, arg2, *, a=1, **kwargs):` if you want to ensure `a` is *only* passed by keyword, matching how `**kwargs` would receive it (and you're on Python 3; not supported on Py2).

Comment: well I want the default and the kwargs in the same list but the defaults are over ridden.