# Apply function with attribute series as arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, apply, series

I have a DataFrame called Tabla. I am applying a function (called `func11`) to each column  which basically is for plotting a specific row against other row (yes, is for plotting a single data point per column).

My question is: how can I pass attribute Series as arguments in my `func11` so I can have a better control of the rows to be plotted?

Part of my Tabla is shown below:

```
                 G13          G42
RH1_0_i      12.7973      25.3097
RH2_0_i     -3.51892      85.2268
RH1_0        6700.17     -8888.33
RH2_0           7613     -7945.33
n1       2.30668e+11  2.23905e+11
n2       2.08436e+11  1.92139e+11
```

So, basically I want to call func11 with extra arguments like `RH1_0_i` or `n1` which are Series attributes.

So far my code is:

```
Tabla.apply(func11)
def func11(x):
    plt.plot(x.RH1_0_i,x.n1)
    plt.plot(x.RH2_0_i,x.n2)
```

What I want is:

```
Tabla.apply(func11,extra_args=(arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4))
def func11(x,extra_args):
    plt.plot(x.arg1,x.arg3)
    plt.plot(x.arg2,x.arg4)
```

Comment: @roganjosh I edited my question.

Comment: You could use kwargs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098549/proper-way-to-use-kwargs-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to the coment posted by amanb I figured out a way to do it:

```
def func12(x,x1,y1,x2,y2):
    X1,X2,Y1,Y2 = x[x1],x[x2],x[y1],x[y2]
    plt.plot(X1,Y1)
    plt.plot(X2,Y2)

Tabla.apply(func12,args=('RH1_0_i','n1','RH2_0_i','n2'))
```

So, in this way I can pass Series attribute as arguments in my function.