# Can't figure out why my object isn't being assigned an attribute

Tags: python, pygame

I can't figure out why when adding a newPerson(), my code isn't assigning a value to the state attribute. I used nearly the same syntax for my color attribute and there's no issue with it.[Here's my newPerson() function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2AyZ.png)

[and here's the constructor for my person class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCVxr.png)

Comment: Please include all the relevant code - and **only** the relevant code - as text in the question itself. See how to create a [mre] so that we can run and reproduce your problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Any chance you can copy and paste your code into the question using code blocks? You would do that by surrounding your code with three backticks (```) before and after.

Answer (score 0):

In your Person class, it looks like when you set self.state, you're assigning it to be a value that you're not passing it.
You're code reads:

```
self.state = kwargs.get('susceptible')
```

but I think it should read:

```
self.state = kwargs.get('state', 'susceptible')
```

This reads the state parameter and sets the default to be susceptible. Here's a link that may be of help: [Proper way to use **kwargs in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098549/proper-way-to-use-kwargs-in-python)