# How to iterate over named keyword arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyword-argument

How do you iterate over keyword arguments in a Python function?
For example, say I have the following method:

```
class Car():
    def start_engine(self, key, *, driver=None, passenger=None,  gas=None):
        for k,v in <ITERATE_OVER_KEYWORD_ARGUMENT>:
            if v is not None:
                print(f"KEY: {k}    VALUE:{v}")

c = Car()
c.start_engine(key, driver="Bob", passenger="Alice")
```

Should print:

```
driver: Bob   
passenger: Alice
```

I didn't want to use `**kwargs` because I wanted to name my arguments.
I can't just call `locals()` because I have other arguments.

I guess I could make a helper function that takes in `**kwargs` and then build a dict, and then I'd call that function with all my keyword arguments, but that seems hacky.

```
def to_dict(**kwargs):
    d = {k:v for k,v in kwargs.items() if v is not None}
    return d
```

That works, but seems like such a strange way to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Is there an acceptable way to to iterate through keyword arguments, or is that bad Python for some reason?

Comment: [Real Python: Python args and kwargs: Demystified](https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proper way to use \*\*kwargs in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098549/proper-way-to-use-kwargs-in-python)

Comment: right. I didn't want to use `**kwargs` because I want to name of variables.

Comment: `kwargs` is already a dictionary, so your don't need to "build" one. Your `to_dict()` does nothing but tear it down (with `**kwargs`), and then puts it back together.

Comment: user3240688: You could use `**kwargs` in the definition, and easily filter out any unknown/undesired keys in it (`kwards` is a dictionary).

Comment: You can use the `inspect` module as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218616/how-to-get-method-parameter-names

Answer (score 4):

In your case they are all optional keyword-only arguments (i.e. arguments with default values) so you can use:

```
for k in self.start_engine.__kwdefaults__:
    v = locals()[k]
```

This simple approach will fail to capture keyword-only arguments without default values. The `Car` shown in your question does not use any, but in case one needs to support those ["required keyword" arguments](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/#specification), you may need to inspect signature:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> class Car:
...     def start_engine(self, key, *, driver=None, passenger=None, dog, gas=None):
...         sig = inspect.signature(self.start_engine)
...         for k, v in sig.parameters.items():
...             if v.kind is inspect.Parameter.KEYWORD_ONLY:
...                 print(k, locals()[k])
...
>>> Car().start_engine("key", gas="unleaded", dog="ridgeback")
driver None
passenger None
dog ridgeback
gas unleaded
```